# Strange Issues with Norwegian -> English Translations

Tags: microsoft-translator

When you translate completely separate sentences from Norwegian to English they come out as exactly the same. Examples are:

"Likte dem veldig godt" and "Greit produkt,fikk ganske fine vipper" (and many others).

First of these should be "Enjoyed them very well" and second one is "Fine product, got pretty nice lashes"

This also happens on the online version of Bing Translator.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed, but the translation is weird:

[image]

They will improve in time. Compare Google translator:

[image]